# How calculate maximum distance for an Infrared floodlight

Tags: visible-light, distance

I got an IR-light 850nm which should radiate about 180m wide, The beam angle is 10°. I measured the following values with a laser power meter.

```
Distance (m)     (mW/cm²)
2,00              1,429;
2,50              0,872;
3,00              0,572;
3,50              0,391;
4,00              0,274;
4,50              0,0274;
5,00              0,0216;
5,50              0,0166;
6,00              0,0142;
6,50              0,0119;
7,00              0,0103;
7,50              0,009;
8,00              0,0079;
8,50              0,007
```

[image]

The diameter from the surface to the wall could not be determined exactly
There were two different rings. The more intensive ring was approx. at 2m = 37cm the outer 70cm at 4m = 40cm and 83cm.

Is there a formula or something else to determine the approximate range(distance) of the floodlight based on these values?

I would be very grateful if you could help me with the task and share your knowledge with me.

in full anticipation
CloneBorg

Comment: Can you tell us what you intend "range" to mean? You could point this thing at the moon, and the radiation would reach. It wouldn't be very bright... are you asking "at what distance is a 10 degree beam 180 m wide"? That could be answered without all the measurements you made. Incidentally your measurements don't quite make sense - did you try plotting them as a function of (inverse square) distance? It should be a straight line... but isn't quite. This suggests it has a size that cannot be neglected at a distance of 2 m.

Comment: Maybe I asked the wrong question.
The infrared floodlight should be able to illuminate a person within a range of 180m (1.8m) or should be visible at night with a corresponding zoom camera.
The manufacturer's specification is,beam angle 10° and the 850nm, which I have no idea how I can control with the measuring instruments (laser power meter; oscilloscope, folding rule (meter) and monitor this spezifikation in a room of 8m.

Comment: Do you know the sensitivity of your camera? What variables do you control? 180m ... you mean 180 cm (which is 1.8 m). Would it not be simpler to do the experiment (see what happens when you use your camera)? It’s still unclear to me what you want to achieve and how this experiment should help.

Comment: No, the distance from the floodlight should be 180m (18000cm), the camera is a Night and Day camera and the lens is also suitable for discreet surveillance. I'm only interested, how to check the indication of the specification, only to avoid a field-test

Comment: Alright, I got confused by the mention of 1.8m in your earlier comment. It all depends on the sensitivity of your camera. Intensity should drop off 4x every time you double the distance; but looking at your measurements there is a 10x drop from 4 to 4.5m which suggests a calibration / measurement error. Again - unless you have a spec for your cameras sensitivity there is nothing sensible we can tell you.

Comment: Correct, the beam from 4.5m is no longer in the focus of the sensor, it is possible to calculate from 2m to 4m or from 4.5 to 8.5 something. It would also be interesting to know what the value mW/cm² at 2m tells me for the practice.

Answer (score 0):

The total power in the beam will be approximately constant with distance - but as the spot of the beam gets bigger as you get further away, the power per unit area decreases. This is called the inverse square law - the diameter of the spot grows linearly with the distance (equal triangles) so the area grows as the square of the distance. If the total power is divided over an area A the intensity is $I=\frac{P}{A}\propto\frac{1}{d^2}$.

I plotted your data, using the inverse square distance  $\frac{1}{d^2}$, as the X coordinate:

[image]

As you can see, there is a clear jump in the data - but the "further away" data seems to have a pretty good linear relationship as we would expect. However, the line doesn't go to zero - this suggests that even if the flood light was turned off, your meter would have indicated a value (due to the IR in the environment, presumably) of about 0.053 mW/cm$^2$ (this is the intercept at X=0, i.e. "infinity").

From the linear fit coefficients ($I = 0.052 + \frac{2.296}{d^2}$), we can estimate the power you would have at 180 m. If we assume the offset of 0.052 is due to your measurement setup (not real) and we only look at the second term, then the intensity at 180 m would be 71 nW / cm$^2$.

A black body at 300 K has a surface emission given by the Stefan-Boltzmann law:

$$E = \sigma T^4 = 459 W/m^2 = 40 mW / cm^2$$

Although your flood light (and camera system) are narrow wavelength, and the above number is across the full spectrum, I expect that your scene will be illuminated more by the warmth of the environment, than by your flood light.

Comment: Thank you very much, for the reference this helps me already further, another question on the above values. 
Is it possible to make a statement with the inverse square law. I have not dealt with the subject in detail yet.